# Is it possible to insert a ToolBar on two lines?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, toolbar, toolbaritems

I wanted to ask if it was possible to insert in Xamarin a ToolBar on two or more lines and, if possible, also how to change the background color.
Thanks

Comment: Could you illustrate (with an image) what you wish to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the toolbar using the `<NavigationPage.TitleView>`

Here is the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar)

And a [blogpost](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-title-view-a-powerful-navigation-view) where it mentions a multi-line toolbar

And you can modify the color of the toolbar using the [BarBackgroundColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.barbackgroundcolor?view=xamarin-forms) (you can do it from your App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FlagDetailsPage()) { BarBackgroundColor=Color.Black };
```